# Contextual word embeddings to estimate likelihood of word given previous words in sentence?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings, language-models

I'd like to use contextual embeddings to estimate the likelihood of word n given the previous n-1 words in a sentence. Which pretrained models would allow me to do this (could I use something like xlnet?)? Is there a recipe somewhere that I could follow? I'm working with a small data set of a couple of thousands sentences from a language corpus and would like to get estimate for particular words in each sentence. I'm beginner in using these kinds of tools

Comment: did you manage to do that?